# Top align text in html input field?

Tags: css

Can I control the vertical alignment of text in an html input field? At the moment (presumably with the browser defaults) my text is too low.

Thanks

Comment: Where are you wanting the text to appear? Your title says "top align", but in your question you say the text is too high.

Comment: Oops, have updated my answer. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure that this is what you want, but to get the text to be vertically centered in an `input` field, you can set the `line-height` CSS property on the input field to the same as the height of that field.

`.inputClass { height:50px; line-height:50px }`

Answer (score 0):

If there is no other CSS impacting the text display inside an input field, I always use `padding`, since it puts the text vertically in the center and also adds some space to the left and right of the field.